# Retrieve Value from PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, configuration

I have an array to store the configuration like this

```
$config = array (
            'db' => array(
                'db1' => array(
                    'dbname' => 'mydatabase', 
                    'user' => 'myusername', 
                    'pass' => 'mypassword', 
                    'host' => 'myhost'
                )
            ),
            'url' => array(
                'homeUrl' => 'http://www.example.com'
            )
         )
```

And I'm writing a function to retrieve the data from the array by passing in a string like `db.db1.dbname` and it supposes to give me `'mydatabase'`

I tried to explode the string into an array in order to get the keys, `db, db1, and dbname`. but after that, I got kinda stuck on how exactly I'm supposed to use them like `$config -> db -> db1 -> dbname` or `$config['db']['db1']['dbname']` in order to get `'mydatabase'`.

Ideally, say I have the function named `read($arg, $array)`, and I would like to retrieve results like this

```
read('db.db1.dbname', $config), returns 'mydatabase'
read('url.homeUrl', $config), returns 'http://www.example.com'
```

Since I don't know how many keys are contained in the string, I need this to be more dynamic.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm really wondering why you would want to do this, but here it goes:

```
function read($item, $config)
{
    $selectors = explode('.', $item);

    $configItem = $config;
    foreach($selectors as $selector) {
        $configItem = $configItem[$selector];
    }

    return $configItem;
}

$config = array (
    'db' => array(
        'db1' => array(
            'dbname' => 'mydatabase', 
            'user' => 'myusername', 
            'pass' => 'mypassword', 
            'host' => 'myhost',
        ),
    ),
    'url' => array(
        'homeUrl' => 'http://www.example.com',
    ),
);

read('db.db1.dbname', $config); // will return mydatabase
```

Note that you would have to check whether the keys exists and throw an error or exception if that's not the case.

Instead of using the function is there a reason why you cannot do:

```
function functionThatNeedsDatabaseInfo($databaseInfo)
{
    // do database stuff
}

functionThatNeedsDatabaseInfo($config['db']['db1']);
```

Comment: wow, this is great. thanks alot. I'm just trying to come up with other ways to retrieve the database constraints. If this isn't good, do you have any suggestion on the most efficient way to store and retrieve database configuration information?

Comment: Why don't you just add the config part of the array which holds the database info directly to the functions that need it?

Comment: @PeeHaa I was trying to follow nettus's tutorial on [organizing php project](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/organize-your-next-php-project-the-right-way/), and it gave an example how to make a `config.php`, so I tried to come up with a way to retrieve the database information from it.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're thinking about JSON

try `$config['db']['db1']['dbname'];`

Answer (score 1):

They are just plain nested arrays.

`$config['db']` will give you the first inner array

`$config['db']['db1']` will give you the array with all the database configurations you're looking for.

`$config['db']['db1']['dbname']`: 'dbname' is the index in the 'db1' array that will give you the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function read($layers, $arr){
    $toReturn = $arr;
    foreach(split('.', $layers) as $layer)
        $toReturn = $toReturn[$layer];
    return $toReturn;
}
```

Why would you want to do this, I haven't the foggiest.  But there you go.

Comment: Uhmmm the config is a multidimensional array and you are overriding the return value. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PeeHaa... What?  I know that.  That's what I did.

Comment: I'm just trying something new, but I'm still open for suggestion. also you might as well change `$toReturn = $arr[$layer];` to `$toReturn = $toReturn[$layer];`

Comment: @user1301840 - What's so wrong with accessing it as an array?

Comment: That is literally the worst reason I've ever heard.

Answer (score -1):

Cast that thing to an Object!   Or rather, cast every array as an object, then you can use it like one.

```
$config = (object) array (
        (object) 'db' => array(
            (object) 'db1' => array(
                'dbname' => 'mydatabase', 
                'user' => 'myusername', 
                'pass' => 'mypassword', 
                'host' => 'myhost'
            )
        ),
        (object) 'url' => array(
            'homeUrl' => 'http://www.example.com'
        )
     )
```

Comment: Performance?  Absolutely none.  Just answering the question, as asked.  Could be a consistency issue from the requested code base.  I don't know.  I just answered the question.

Comment: Womp Womp.  Question changed.